# Why do I get a phase of the FFT of a cosine function when the phase is zero?

Tags: fft, dft, phase

I'm trying to find the phase of a cosine function with the FFT but I don't understand the results from the plots. I did two separate examples for two phases $\phi$: $\phi_1 = 0$ and $\phi_2 = \pi/3$. They end up with nearly the same results but with different values for the phase. I would appreciate any help.

$\phi = 0$:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift
from skimage.filters import window


l = np.arange(0,50,.025)
y = 0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.4*l) 
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(y)
f = fftfreq(len(l), np.diff(l)[0])
yf = fft(y, norm = "forward")

phase = np.angle(yf)
plt.figure(2)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.plot(phase[:l.size//2])
plt.show()

phase = np.angle(yf)
phase[np.abs(yf) < 0.1] = 0
plt.figure(3)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.plot(phase[:l.size//2])
plt.show()
```

Results: the first figure is the cosine, the second is the phase and the third is the phase but with a threshold value added so that all the smaller values than this threshold are set to zero:

[image]

$\phi = \pi/3$:

```
l = np.arange(0,50,.025)
y = 0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*0.4*l + np.pi/3) 
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(y)
f = fftfreq(len(l), np.diff(l)[0])
yf = fft(y, norm = "forward")

phase = np.angle(yf)
plt.figure(4)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.plot(phase[:l.size//2])
plt.show()

phase = np.angle(yf)
phase[np.abs(yf) < 0.1] = 0
plt.figure(5)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.plot(phase[:l.size//2])
plt.show()
```

Results: The first figure is the cosine, the second is the phase and the third is the phase but with a threshold value added so that all the smaller values than this threshold equal to zero:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct. You're generating a pure cosine at frequency $0.4Hz$, sampled with a period $T_s = 0.025s$.
When taking the DFT, the resulting frequency grid will have each bin containing the values for frequencies $f_k = k /(NT_s)$.
For $f = 0.4Hz$, that gives you bin $k = fNT_s = 0.4\cdot2000\cdot0.025 = 20$

Look at the value of the phase at that bin, and you'll find your plots are correct. The first plot shows a phase $\phi = 0$, the second shows $\phi = 1.047 = \pi/3$. I'm not sure why you didn't expect that result?

If you're wondering about why there are phase values at other frequencies, please refer to [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10642/63763)

**EDIT**
Seems you're confused about not getting the $Hz$ values on the x-axis. To have those, you need to map each BIN number $k$ to its corresponding frequency through $f_k = k \cdot F_s / N$
Create a vector `freq_vector` (something like `freq_vector = (0:2000-1)*40/2000` ) using that equation and then `plt.plot(freq_vector, y)`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I made this example so that the cosine frequency would in fact not smear out and would give precise values. There are 2000 samples therefore there are 2000/2 FFT bins. The sampling rate is 1/0.025 = 40 Hzvand Nyquist freq 20Hz- So therefore the frequency bin resolution is: 20Hz/1000 FFT bins = 0.02 Hz/bin. So I thought the frequency of the cosine can be anything as long as its divisible by 0.02. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you thinking you're doing **anything** wrong? I just wrote out an answer showing you that there's nothing wrong with what you did! What are you not happy with?

Comment: Like you said, because of how you set the cosines, there is no smearing so you're getting the exact phase values that you would expect! The "noise" is just a result of computation noise, as explained in the [linked answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10642/63763)

Comment: Your point about the phase for 0 and pi/3 being correct at 20 doesn't make sense. As I wrote in my comment, I thought the cosine frequency was an integer times 0.02 Hz/bin. So I thought I would get legitimate values and not just 20. So how can I get, for both phase = 0 and phase = pi/3 those actual values and not just 20?

Comment: And btw where does k come from? It's not clear where this equation comes from. I feel I'm almost there to having an AHA moment but I just need a bit more help from you!

Comment: From how you  put it there, that means the k increases with the amount of steps would I find counterintuitive.

Comment: Can you join this chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138596/fftdsp  we can chat there

Comment: Pretty sure my point does make sense, but happy to chat more

Comment: Hey, do you have time now to chat? I just read your comment in the chat and I have a few questions